# Android Media Player: how to play audio offline by url?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

In my app(using **kotnlin**), i need to play some audios from url and they are can be big, like ~50mb, so the main thing is - i want to play this audios also offline if they are started listeting by user. In other words, if i press play - the audio start playing, but if I will turn off the internet after some time, I can still listen to the audio to the end, how can i do this using andoid-mediaPlayer?

Comment: I think the media player by default when it gets the url it will use it as streaming, so no internet, no streaming.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant you can download this file (use DownloadManager for example) in background and if the connection will be lost you should catch it and resume playing with the downloaded file.
When playing finish just remove the file.

Comment: I thought about this option, but I want to understand if there is some built-in mechanism in android-mediaPlayer for requesting a full download by url.